# Use @ symbol in a rails method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, method-names

Is there any way for me to use the '@' symbol in a rails method name? e.g.

```
def @method_name

end
```

Rails doesn't seem to like it.

I want to do it to adhere to some external conventions (external to rails).

Comment: The simple thing I can say is that `@` symbol has special meaning to many programming languages. Thus, any convention that would enforce its use is (in my own oppinion) a wrong convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
define_method('@test') do
  'test'
end
```

this method then has to be called with:

```
model.send('@test')
```

I would not recommend it, since it will be ugly and complicated and that is against the philosophy of ruby. But it can be done.

Kind of like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVpVHGiELf8

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using:

In my controller:

```
@job = Job.first
render :json @job.as_json( methods: :@id )
```

In Job.rb

```
define_method('@id') do
  return url_for( :controller => 'jobs', :action => 'create', :id => id )
end
```

Now when I render my json i get:

```
"@id":"http://localhost:3000/jobs?id=1"
```

Note: @id is to comply with the syntax of json-ld